# Is there a way to prevent client from sending unknown properties/keys in express api?

Tags: node.js, express, validation, security, express-validator

I'm building an API in express and I have a few routes. I am also using `express-validator` to validate what the client sends. This gives an error if the client sends the right keys and the values for those keys fail the validation defined from the `express-validator` schema.

However, the issue I'm having now, is that I can't really check whether the client is sending a random key.

Here's an illustration. API can accept the following:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "email": "johndoe@example.com"
}
```

Validator will check if `firstName`, `lastName`, and `email` are valid and accept the data.

Now let's say I send the following:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"    
}
```

This  also  works because  the validator only requires `firstName` and `lastName`. `email` is optional, so it still  goes through.

Now, let's try something else:

```
{
    "firstName": "234839248923",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "email": "johndoe@gmail.com"
}
```

In the above, the validation fails, and we get an error because `firstName` can't be just numbers.

So far, so good.

Now, here's another case:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
    "randomKeyIDontNeed": "I don't need this"
}
```

The above works perfectly and goes through, even though there is the `randomKeyIDontNeed` which is sent from the client.

I can't find a way with `express-validator` to check if random keys are sent and give an error.

Is there a way to check that only those 3 keys are allowed, whether required or optional, and give the client an error if they send the wrong keys?

Here's one way I am thinking of doing it, but I'm not sure if that makes sense:

> 1. Have an array of keys which are allowed. e.g `arr = ["firstName,"lastName", "email"]`
> 2. Get all the keys from `req.body`.
> 3. Check if keys from `req.body` are in array `arr`. If not, return an error.

Is there a simpler, cleaner way of doing this?

Right now, whenever a random key is sent, it's not being used in the back-end and it doesn't really affect anything. So, is there even a point to validate the random keys?

What are the repercussions of not doing the validation for the random keys?

Comment: did this solution help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into using [express-joi-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-joi-validation). It does validation on types for the given keys, and prevents the user from passing other values.

Here is a file I have for my validators for some Stripe routes

```
const Joi = require('joi');

exports.postPaymentMethod = Joi.object({
    paymentMethodId: Joi.string().required()
});

exports.deletePaymentMethod = Joi.object({
    paymentMethodId: Joi.string().required()
});
```

And here is how I use them.

```
const validator = require('express-joi-validation').createValidator({});
router.delete('/payment-methods', validator.body(deletePaymentMethod), ash(async (req, res) => {
    // validated body is passed here, safe to use w/o lots of error checking
    var paymentMethodId = req.body.paymentMethodId;
}));
```

Comment: Was perfect! Thank you!